# Preventing generation of CSS files

Tags: css, sass

I am working with an Angular-6 project. I use SCSS for styling and also configured the project to always generate SCSS while creating a new component.

But when I save SCSS file it automatically generates CSS file. I want to prevent this behavior and want to make my folder structure clean.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Share your configuration please

Comment: are you using webpack or angular cli ?

Comment: why you don't want to generate css? that's not the entire idea?

Comment: @PranayRana I am using Angular CLI

Comment: @Nestor I don't want to generate CSS because it is not in use. I am using SCSS and also links SCSS file only to my component.

Answer (score 0):

You can always prefix your filename with an underscore, so that Sass will treat is as a [partial](https://sass-lang.com/guide) and therefore ignore it.

I.e. rename `project.scss` to `_project.scss`.